# Creating class dynamically

Tags: c++, oop

I need some suggestion. I am reading a file which has input like this

001 100
110 000
...
..

These are consecutive input and output pairs.

Now I need to read these 1 and 0 for further processing. I need to have an array like input[0]= {0,0,1} input[1] = {1,1,0} ....for all the inputs. I will do bitwise compare, xor, or.. etc with the input and output pair. I was thinking about creating a class so that after reading the input/outputs I can create objects of that class where all the required functions will be overloaded. As an example, this case the object will be an array of 3 elements and will consist of only 1 and 0.

Now the problem is, the number of 1 and 0s can vary. Is it possible to create a class where the member will be an undefined sized array? Or is there any other way around?

I am new in this. So, I would appreciate to get some help.

Answer (score 2):

Use [std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset), `std::string` and `std::vector`.

```
std::string bits = "001";
std::bitset<3> b(bits);
```

`std::bitset` already provides bitwise operations for you.

The create an `std::vector<std::bitset<3>>` of them and work with that.

Comment: Hi, thanks, But I can only know the number of bits after reading the file. So, can I use it bitset dynamically?

Comment: @skeptic: Unfortunately not, you would need [boost::dynamic_bitset](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html) to do it at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. dynamic_bitset seems awesome :)

Comment: How do I check if my installed gcc will support boost ? Thanks.

Comment: Look at the bottom of [the release notes page](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_49_0.html) for compilers tested. However, you shouldn't have any problems unless your version of gcc is extremely old (in which case you should upgrade).

Answer (score 1):

Make your data member a `std::vector`. You can use `push_back` to add elements onto the end, and a whole other whack of stuff. Elements can be accessed just like an array. There are lots of good references on it out there.

Even better, just use vectors in the first place and overload the operators to take two vectors.